# ListData.svc gives a 500 error when querying some lists

Tags: 2010, listdata.svc, powerpivot

I'm trying to use `ListData.svc` to retrieve details from a SharePoint list, but I get the following error:

**Error Message:**

> Cannot connect to the specified feed. Verify the connection and try
>   again. Reason: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal
>   Server Error.

**Call Stack:**

```
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Common.DataSourceBasic.UpdateDataFeedParameters(ConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder, IDataSource dataSource, Boolean checkFeedValid)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Common.DataSourceBasic.GetCurrentConnectionString(Boolean checkFeedValid)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Common.DataSourceBasic.ClickTestConnection(Object progressControl)
```

I can retrieve data from other lists in the same site. The error occurs very quickly so it doesn't appear to be a timeout. I get the error when calling the service from the browser and from Excel Power Pivot. Nothing suspicious is being logged to ULS or the Windows event logs.

Comment: What is your URL and filter/query?

Comment: http://sharepoint/site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/listname

Answer (score 2):

Does the list have any calculated columns? If so then PowerPivot cannot connect to such list

Answer (score 1):

Yea, took me a bit to find, but the issue is simple and also stupid. Power Pivot has issues with importing "Calculated Fields" - But I think these are Sharepoint created and might still work with Infopath created Calculated fields, hope this helps someone. Once I removed the calculated fields I stopped getting this error immediately.